# How to rewrite the code to open link on Chrome custom tab

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

How can I rewrite the code to open link on Chrome custom tab:

```
imageView5 = (AppCompatImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view5);

imageView5.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view3) {
        Intent intent1 =
            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://mekotube.com/muslim/"));
        ((HOMEActivity) getContext()).startActivity(intent1);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

The documentation for Custom Tabs is available [here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs).

On the Custom Tabs [Github repo](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client), There is a [set of demos](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/tree/master/demos/src/main/java/org/chromium/customtabsdemos), showing how to use the API.

Check out the [simple demo app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/master/demos/src/main/java/org/chromium/customtabsdemos/SimpleCustomTabActivity.java), showing how to open it.

I'd also recommend checking out the [demo on how to use the Custom Tabs Service](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/master/demos/src/main/java/org/chromium/customtabsdemos/ServiceConnectionActivity.java) to improve speed when opening the page.

Make sure to check out the [best practices](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs#bestpractices) as well, as they contain valuable hints on how to handle multiple browsers among other stuff.

Here's an extract from the docs, showing how to open a simple tab, without any customisation or connecting to the Custom Tabs service.

1 - Add the Custom Tabs Support Library to your Gradle build file.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
}
```

2 - Use the Support Library to open a link:

```
String url = "https://paul.kinlan.me/";
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
```